# Infest a terran base

Tags: starcraft-2

In his tutorial Video at [csnstarcraft Training Camp - How to Improve Efficiently](http://csnstarcraft.com/home/guide/82) there is a scene, where the terran player draws back his base and it seems to be infested:

[image]

How did this happen? How can you infest a terran base this way? Or does it happen automatically, when creep spreads under it?

Comment: oh, poor Lowko fails in his tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zerg unit "Overseer" (upgraded from a regular overlord) has two abilities. One of them is called "Contaminate" and it infests a building, preventing it from operating for 30 seconds.

During that time, the building can still be damaged and everything, but the player is unable to issue any commands to it, and any units or research queued up is paused (not reset) until the contaminate expires.

Comment: Does Contaminate also prevent Terran buildings from moving?